# How do you get resize2fs to actually fit to your filesystem?

Tags: unix

Using Ubuntu Mint here, 20.1 Cinnamon.

I'm trying to reduce a SD partition as much as possible, but when use resize2fs

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdb2
sudo resize2fs -M /dev/sdb2
```

it resizes the partition to around 7 GB rather than the expected around 5 GB. df confirms as much:

```
/dev/sdb2       6,4G  4,4G  1,7G  73%
```

It is the last partition (sdb1 is the system-boot partition).

Why is it showing that behavior? I would expect it to be a lot closer to the actual filesystem.

The result of the tune2fs command is the following:

```
Filesystem volume name:   writable
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          b09bb4c8-de4d-4ce6-a93f-30c4c9241a58
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         unsigned_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              417664
Block count:              1688722
Reserved block count:     69406
Overhead blocks:          34024
Free blocks:              512908
Free inodes:              294800
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      439
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8032
Inode blocks per group:   502
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Aug  9 14:05:18 2022
Last mount time:          Mon Feb 13 23:27:27 2023
Last write time:          Mon Feb 13 23:27:41 2023
Mount count:              2
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Mon Feb 13 17:13:10 2023
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          10 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      24701edc-0cdd-48cd-a0ff-573147f7acac
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x174a0a99
```

Comment: Can you [attach](https://serverfault.com/posts/1122844/edit) `tune2fs -l /dev/sdb2`?

Comment: Done, thank you.